# How to get Child Component variables and functions from Parent in TypeScript file

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

Quite new to Angular but I know you can set up children variables from the html code and also get stuff from it using events but my question is more related to getting the actual ChildComponent from the ParentComponent class.

Can't I just have the *Children* as a variable in the *Parent* so I can get/set variables and call functions from there? Or is this not how Angular is suposed to work?

I tried adding everything to **NgModule** and injecting the Children into the Parent constructor but Angular told me:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ParentComponent -> ChildrenComponent]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ParentComponent -> ChildrenComponent]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenComponent!

I can provide some code examples of what I have if needed but if someone can point me to the right question/resources if this is possible or just explain why it is not should be enough :)

Thanks!

Comment: Check out Angular's Tour of Heros example.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1
Most beginner questions are explained directly in here with examples. I find that people who take the time and actually follow along get the hang of Angular much faster.

Comment: Yeah but everything there is done using the Html as "glue", while I'd love to be able to get everything directly from the component.ts file. Since I see this not mentioned anywhere I understand I may not be thinking about the problem in the "Angular way" but wan't to know for sure before switching quite some code.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I misread your question. It looks like @jithesh-kumar has got you-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code:

```js
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

// Ceate object of ChildComponent
@ViewChild( ChildComponent ) childcomponent: ChildComponent;

// Accessing childComponent variable using object
childcomponent.variablename;

// Accessing method of ChildComponent using object 
childcomponent.MethodName();
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined.

I created the childcomponentvariable outside of the constructor with the member variables, is taht how it's meant to be used? I'll be looking ad docs for ViewChild anyway, thanks :)

Comment: try this. Initialize your variable inside ngOnInit(){}

Comment: I can't really initialize there it sinze I can't manually inject the child component constructor dependencies, can I?

Comment: Ok, I understood what you meant. It seems to be partially working even though I still get the undefined error. I'll have to keep taking a look at it tomorrow. Much thanks!